# Disabling Anchor Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I need help making my Anchor button not clickable after it has been clicked once before.

Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance

HTML CODE:

```
            <div class="text-center">
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-success" id="createGameButton" onclick="addGame();">Create Coinflip</a>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function addGame() 
{
var side = $("#side").val();
var steamid = $("#steamid").val();
var amount = $("#amount").val();
var buttonText = document.getElementById('createGameButton').innerHTML;

if(buttonText=='Create Coinflip')
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'addGame.php', 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: 'side=' + side + '&steamid=' + steamid + '&amount=' + amount, 
        dataType: 'text', 
        success: function (data) 
        {
            document.getElementById('game-alert').innerHTML = data;
            $("#game-alert").fadeIn();
            refreshGames();
            document.getElementById('createGameButton').innerHTML = 'Create Coinflip';
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Use jQuery register a handler which will be called only once

Comment: @goto I tired a number of things such as                  $("#anchorid").off('click');

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

remove `onclick="addGame();"` and use [**`one`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> **.one()**
>
> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element per event type.

so:-

```
$('#createGameButton').one("click", addGame);
```

Comment: I don't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

adding a flag on top of your function is a general technique for stopping execution :

```
function addGame() {
   if(addGame.flag) 
   return;
   addGame.flag = true;
   // rest of procedure ....
```

- `addGame.flag` adds a property to the function addGame
- the first time it runs it sets flag to true
- once flag is true the function will return right away

Comment: I added this code and it just breaks it and does not create a game when I try to create one.

Comment: here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/hz8u6ttb/) ; but in your case it's probably better to remove listener ... (BenG answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove classes to adapt the behavior of your click function.

The html code (without the onclick)

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-success" id="createGameButton" >Create Coinflip</a>
```

The javascript code

```
$("#createGameButton").click(function(){

  //if we have not clicked already on this link
  if( ! $(this).hasClass("already-clicked") )
  {
      $.ajax(
      {
          /* [...your normal code...] */
          success: function (data)
          {
              /* [...your normal code...] */
              $(this).addClass("already-clicked")
          }
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by adding a class 'disabled' in the button, [Here is JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bewonaxono/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: its an `<a>` tag, not a button.

Comment: It works both ways, he is using bootstrap and using btn class for that element, so it hardly matter it is a or button or anything.

Comment: It does because it is a anchor not a button.

Comment: Ok add the class 'disabled' in your anchor tag, Have you seen the bin i have created? It works and you should use bootstrap classes for such purpose, It triggers you ajax request only once.

Comment: if(buttonText=='Create Coinflip')
{
  $('#createGameButton').addClass('disabled');//This will work, $.ajax will execute once and then it will disable your button for making further requests. There are many ways to achieve it like you can create flag but as I told you earlier it is bootstrap so use bootstrap classes for such purpose.